# Prolog Assignment Suggestion

Tags: prolog

i been asking by lecturer to write a Prolog application with 20 facts, 10 rules and 10 queries but this seems easy but i just can think out a scenario/idea of a project like any business rules.

We not allow to program family tree.

can anyone suggest ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do something like the game 'Guess Who'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a small expert system for personal computer configurations? A PC is built out of components (processor, motherboard, RAM). For each component category there are several options (vendor, type, price) and some components might require or exclude each other.

Comment: OK. This seems like a good idea. 

What are the rules are available for this scenario because i need to write 10 rules, 20 facts and 10 queries? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you decide to use this example, you'll have to analyse the problem domain into facts/rules/queries yourself. I'm not doing your homework for you.

Comment: I go for loan evaluation expert system. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine patients taking many different medicines.

Some pills go into interaction with another,

in some cases - positive interaction, in other cases - bad interaction.

Another thing is, that some pills share some substances. So, taking a few different pills, might result in exceeding daily limit of one of consisting substances.

To sum it up:

Program input: set of medicines

Program output: information about interactions.

Basic version: Return True if no bad interaction, Return False if there is bad interaction.

Complex version: Whatever detailed information you imagine, that might be helpful :).